Does $\vec F=I\int\mathrm d\vec{l}\times \vec{B}$ give the force on a current carrying wire when it is in motion?
The standard derivation of the force on a current-carrying wire, $\vec{F}=I\int\mathrm d\vec{l}\times \vec{B}$, involves calculating the magnetic force on the moving charges within a wire element $\mathrm d\vec{l}$ to give $$\vec{\mathrm dF}=\mathrm dq\, \vec{v}\times\vec{B}=I\mathrm d\vec{l}\times\vec{B}\,.$$ This relies on the fact that the instantaneous direction of motion of the charges at each point is given by $\mathrm d\vec{l}$. However, this is no longer true when the wire is in motion as a whole. In that situation, it is only the drift velocity that is in the same direction as the wire; the overall velocity is intead $\vec{v}=\vec{v}_{wire}+\vec{v}_d$. Why is it that most electromagnetism texts I can find assume that the original formula remains valid even if the wire is in motion?
I have a guess at what's going on but I'm not really sure about the correctness of it: essentially, since the wire is neutral, at each point, for every moving charge $\mathrm dq$, there is an equal and opposite charge $-\mathrm dq$ (from the lattice of positive ions in a conductor, say) that moves with $\vec{v}_{wire}$ so that the magnetic force on the system due to the motion of the moving charges with the wire as a whole actually cancels out.
I would really appreciate if someone could either verify my conjecture or prove an alternate explanation of what's going on.

You are correct; although the usual simple derivation works only for stationary conductor, the result is more general and holds for moving conductor as well.
One way to see it is the argument you gave - net current density is not affected by the motion of the conductor (at least in first approximation), because there is just as much positive charge as negative charge with velocity of the conductor, and only the relative velocity of the mobile charge affects net current density and force.
A different way is this. We can derive the formula for force
$$
\mathbf F' = \int I'd\mathbf s' \times \mathbf B'_{ext}~dV'
$$
in the frame where the conductor is at rest (primed frame). In a different frame (unprimed frame), where the conductor is moving, there can be also electric field $\mathbf E = \mathbf v\times \mathbf B'_{ext}$ in addition to magnetic field, and in general it can act with non-zero force.
But if net force due to this electric field is zero (e.g. due to symmetry or vanishing charge distribution on the conductor), then net force on the conductor in unprimed frame $\mathbf F$ will, in first approximation, be equal to force in the primed frame, so it can be given by the above formula:
$$
\mathbf F = \int I'd\mathbf s' \times \mathbf B'_{ext}~dV'.
$$
Since also current $I$, configuration of the conductor in space and field $\mathbf B_{ext}$ in unprimed frame have, in first approximation, the same values as in the primed frame, we can replace the primed with the unprimed quantities, and we get
$$
\mathbf F = \int Id\mathbf s \times \mathbf B_{ext}~dV.
$$
So the formula applies also in the frame where the conductor moves.
In other words, provided the quantities involved (force, current, configuration of wire in space, magnetic field) have the same values in both frames, the formula has to apply in both frames.

I just realize with your answer that I misinterpreted the question completely and not answered it properly! I think this is the right answer. Would the correction terms of primed and unprimed quantities, proportional to $v/c$?

@Ruffolo I think the differences are proportional to $v^2/c^2$. If they were proportional to $v/c$, they would depend on sign of $v$, so on direction of motion, which in magnetic field with vanishing electric field is implausible.

Your conjecture is not true. Consider the following cases:

If the magnetic field is non uniform : the formula $F = I d\vec{l} \times \vec{B}$ will be applicable but due to the change in magnetic flux the induced current will oppose the change and hence the current in the wire will decrease but won't cancel out fully.

If the magnetic field is uniform:
then there won't be any induce current and Therefore the above equation $F = I d\vec{l} \times \vec{B}$ will work fine at all points in the field.


